# PHP cURL timeout is not working

Tags: php, curl

I'm having a server issue. I'm running a local server (for developing) and I've changed my local server from MAMP to XAMPP. However, on XAMPP, the cURL option `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS` or `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS` gives me the next error:

> Warning: curl_setopt() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given

Is this because of the PHP or cURL version? Maybe a configuration setting?

`curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS, 2500);`

Additional information:

- OSX 10.6.8
- PHP 5.3.1
- cURL 7.19.7

Thanks in advance.

---

Edit: There seems to be some confusion about the error and the variable to set. The error states that parameter **2** is invalid. Not parameter **3**. So the `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS` seems to be the issue.

```
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS, 2500);
            ^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^
parameter:     #1                 #2               #3
```

Fun fact: `var_dump(CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS);` displays `string(25) "CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS"`. Just like the error states, it's a string instead of a float.

Comment: Have you tried `curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS, 2500.0);`?

Comment: Try to check for non printable character (non breakable space) between `,` and `2500` and if it's okay try using cast operator `(int)` before value.

Comment: @Sim that's `double/float`, not `long`, this shouldn't work.

Comment: @Sim Look at the error. It's about parameter 2 which is the `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS` constant. I don't think my problem lies in the value to set. Either way, I've tested it and it did not help. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Can you do a cast for the constant? As in `(int)CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS`. I am not entirely sure if this is legit :)

Comment: @Sim The error disappears, but the value is 0. I highly doubt that both `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS` and `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS` should be 0.

Comment: Strange. Can you try using another version of `php_curl.dll`?

Comment: And what does `print_r(get_defined_constants(true))` give you?

Comment: @SalmanA I think the problem lies in PHP itself, since the constant doesn't exist or is invalid. The code you gave did not display `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS` as I expected.

Comment: As a side note CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS has a bug/feature with *nix OSes [http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#104597].  `curl_setopt($soapAction, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);`  helped me to get CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS working

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For some reason, `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS` is defined incorrectly in your version of PHP. I'd check with whatever distribution of PHP you're using and find out whether it's a general bug.

The correct value is `156`: you should be able to use this instead:

```
curl_setopt($this->ch, /*CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS */ 156, 2500);
```

NB that you *really really **really*** need to add comments explaining why you're doing this.

Comment: Thanks for this, but can I ask how you came to know what the solution is? There are lots of questions, on SO and elsewhere, about CURL timeouts not working - is it possible that a similar fix could be the answer to CURLOPT_TIMEOUT not working? I and others have this. I can open a new question for this if you think that's the way to go. So to sum up, can I ask where the documentation is that provides the '156' in your answer?

Comment: @GeoffKendall Sorry, it's a long time ago that I wrote this answer. The comments above show the problem, but I can't remember what research I might have done. I got the value from my own system, by doing `var_dump(CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS);` I don't think it's defined anywhere.

Comment: Thanks lonesome day, I did 'sniff the coffee' and google it - it's here http://laprbass.com/RAY_get_defined_constants.php and elsewhere. As it turned out the constants were fine for me, but it was worth a check.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and this solved it for me. Just add this line to the top of your script. It defines the missing constant only when not defined yet.

> if (!defined(CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS)) define('CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS', 156);