# PHP Curl doesn't return a response

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to get the response back from an API using curl in php but for some reason it fails. However, when I open the API call link in a browser it works fine. Furthermore, if I try to get the response with curl after I've opened the link in the browser curl works but if I change the  $url variable to a new link it again stops working until I open it in the browser again.

Here is my code, don't worry about the api key it's just a test:

```
<?php 
set_time_limit(30); 
$API_KEY = "ak_wujpBbfefrmxDleyAmnqtFpqAcmey";

$url = 'https://www.google.com/'; 
$api_call = "https://www.screenshot-website.com/api/$API_KEY?url=$url&type=tablet";

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => $api_call,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS => 30000,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS => 30000 )
);

$response = json_decode(curl_exec($curl), true);

if($errno = curl_errno($curl)) {
    $error_message = curl_strerror($errno);
    echo "cURL error ({$errno}):\n {$error_message}"; 
}

curl_close($curl); ?>

<img src="<?php echo $response['image']; ?>">
```

I get no errors at all.

Comment: What's $response when it does not work?

Comment: symptoms don't make any sense. Opening url in browser is completely disconnected from a curl request from server

Comment: According to gettype() it's NULL

Comment: @charlietfl indeed it's really confusing

Comment: Just a wild guess: Maybe the API is dependent on a special user agent string?

Comment: "It fails" "It doesn't work" Eh

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `$response` is null.

Comment: Also your API call doesn't seem to have anything in common with [the documented API](https://www.screenshot-website.com/api). You have no secret key and you did not MD5 the token.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit the doc on the site is irrelevant

Comment: @Petar: Um, I disagree...

Comment: @wumm: So? Of far more interest is what `curl_exec($curl)` returns. _Basic_ debugging, people.

Comment: @wumm: Nothing in the question or the comments tells us that the return of `curl_exec($curl)` is `null` (in fact, this function [never returns `null`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php)!). Pay more attention to the factual accuracy of your own statements before being a d!ck about mine, mmkay?

Comment: Actually NULL is returned by the json_decode, just tried the curl_exec($curl) using gettype() and it apparently returns an empty string

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The first comment is `What's $response when it does not work?`, Then the OP's first response is, `According to gettype() it's NULL`...Just saying.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yeah, you are right. I did overlooked the json_decode.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: Oh god why is nobody here capable of basic reading comprehension? `$response` is NULL, yes, but _who cares about that_? `$response` is the result of `json_decode`. Your **first step** should be abstracting that away and looking at the result of `curl_exec`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Fair enough.

Comment: I think it has something to with the fact that when you open the api call link using a brand new $url it takes ~3s for the site to respond but if you repeat the request it's much faster. Don't know why that would be a problem for curl though.

Comment: I've just tested your code on my server and it works fine. The result is: `<img src="http://screenshot-website.s3.amazonaws.com/571463_1410035579119.png">` However, I did get notices about some of your `CURLOPT_` constants; [check them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9063006/560648).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Try changing the URL to a different site and see if that works

Comment: Are you sure `curl_strerror` is supported by your PHP version ? It requires `5.5.0`. If its not supported it would spit an error, assuming you have error reporting on `ini_set("display_errors",1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` in top of file.

Comment: @vlzvl I've commented it out and still nothing

Comment: Perhaps you should consider asking the provider for support? Especially since this is paid-for, they have no docs online, and you don't appear to be using the documented API.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm the provider :D

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit did a different $url worked for you or did it return nothing?

Comment: @Petar Vasilev, did you tried posted answer below? i tried and i got the screenshot.

Comment: @vlzvl I did try to set the ssl verify to false but that didn't change anything

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is with the "https" since curl set ssl_verifier to true 
*"The problem is that cURL has not been configured to trust the server’s HTTPS certificate."* you can read the full information [here.](http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/)

You could try setting this option:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```